# How to call function in CallbackQueryHandler based from what user chose?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Example:

```
AGAIN = range(1)
TOKEN = 'token'


def start(update, context):
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("again", callback_data='again')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("stop", callback_data='stop')]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text(
            text="Hi!\n-----\nThat's it, again?",
            reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return AGAIN


def again(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    if query.data == 'again':
        start()

    elif query.data == 'stop':
        cancel()


def cancel(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Thank You, if you want open the menu, just type /start')
    return ConversationHandler.END


def main():
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            AGAIN: [CallbackQueryHandler(again)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
    )

    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How to do the again part? where if user choose 'again' --> run start(), if user choose 'stop'--> run cancel(). I've tried adding new state with MessageHandler or CommandHandler, but it's not working because there is no user message as input after .

Comment: have you tried replacing `start()`  with `start(update, context)`? as well as canel?

Comment: @Ali yes, but i got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply_text'`

Comment: that's because you use `update.message` to reply. When a `callback_query` update is received, `message` will be null. You should have a condition there, `if update.message is not None` use that to reply, if it is none, use `callback_query` to reply.

Comment: yep it works, thanks dude!